# change queue pointer member's value will need to weired fault in c++

Tags: c++

I am a new beginner in c/c++, and I encountered a very weired problem. this simple code below will lead to segmentation fault. 
can anyone tell me How can this problem happens?
Thank you very much

```
    #include <queue>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class hhh{
    private:
    public:
        int *root=NULL;
        void cons(){
            queue<int*> q;
            q.push(root);
            q.front()=new int(8);
            cout<<*(q.front())<<endl;
            cout<<*root<<endl;
        }
    };
    int main(){
        hhh *h1=new hhh();
        h1->cons();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`q.push(root);` copies `root` in the queue, so when you do `q.front()=new int(8);`, you are modifying the pointer in the queue, not the initial `root`.

So your `root` variable is always `NULL`, so `cout<<*root<<endl;` gives you a segmentation fault because you cannot dereference a null pointer.

But aside from the explanation, you should not do manual allocation with `new` / `delete`. C++ is not like Java or C#, everything is not a reference.